# Removing Zeros After Decimal

Tags: ms-access

I have a field that is defaulted to 4 places after the decimal point.  The field's data type is Number, field size double, and the decimal places is set to 4.  I cannot change these attributes.

When running a query, how do I drop the zeros for the following

Entered Data = 0.5000%
Desired Output = .5%

Entered Data = 0.2500%
Desired Output = .25%

Entered Data = 100%
Desired Output = 100%

Is there an expression or function I can use?

Comment: Are you sure you want no leading zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also wish *100%* to be displayed correctly, you need something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Format([NumberField], IIf(t >= 1, "0%", ".##%")) AS TextValue
FROM
    YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use function Format$.

```
SELECT Format$([MyTable].[Data],".##%") AS [Desired]
FROM [MyTable];
```